# Ionic center text vertically and horizontally on screen

Tags: ionic-framework

I'm trying to vertically align my text on my screen. I've read through [the docs](http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#grid-vertically-align) on how to do this. But I'm still not having any luck. This is my code:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col col-center text-center">
    <h4 class="gray">This text is in the center of the screen</h4>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 17):

**HTML**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col">
        <div class="text-center">
            <h5 style="text-align: center;">This text is in the center of the screen</h5>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you, although it's not working.. It's almost exactly the same as what I have

Answer (score 13):

This works on Ionic Framework 3.0.1:

HTML:

```
<ion-content padding>
 <div>
  <h4 class="gray">This text is in the center of the screen</h4>
 </div>
</ion-content>
```

SASS:

```
ion-content {
 div {
   height: 100%;
   width: 100%;
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
   align-items: center;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Try this solution:

1.Add new css styles:

```
.home .scroll-content {
  display: table !important;
  width: 100% !important;
  height: 100% !important;
  margin-top: -50px; /* the height of the centered content */
  text-align: center;
}
.home .scroll {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

2.Apply `home` class to `ion-view`:

`<ion-view class="home">`

[demo](http://play.ionic.io/app/38f9f799cd56)

Answer (score 3):

How about specify the "height"?
Anyway, centralize your text in horizontal, you can also use `align="center"`.
(To make it clear, I added the color to row and col.)

```
<div class="row" style="height: 900px; background-color: blue;">
  <div class="col col-center" style="background-color: red;>
    <h4 class="gray" align="center">This text is in the center of the screen</h4>
  </div>
</div>
```